# how to update the selected date on prime faces calendar based so as to render/hide a panel content

Tags: jsf, calendar, primefaces

I have a  component,where users can choose to set any date at all even null, but when the date is not null, it should render a panel to allow for other options. But, the date is not getting updated and is always null as a result it never renders the panel. Help needed on this. Below is my code:

```
        <p:calendar id="dt"
                    value="#{user.deadline}"
                    pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"                        
                    showOn="button"
                    mindate="#{userr.minDate}">
            <f:validator validatorId = "dateValidator"/>
            <f:attribute name="minDate" value="#{user.minDate}" />

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{user.updateDeadlineDate}" update=":userForm:userReminderForm"/>
        </p:calendar>

        <p:panel id= "myPanel" rendered="#{user.getDeadline != null}">
         .. some component that needs user.deadline

        </p:panel>
```

snippet from my bean:

```
   public Date getDeadline() {
    return deadline;
     }

public void setDeadline(Date deadline) {
    this.deadline=deadline;
      }
 public void updateDeadlineDate(DateSelectEvent event) {

    this.setDeadline(event.getDate());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your update target is probably wrong (nested forms `:userForm:userReminderForm` are invalid in HTML/JSF), maybe you wanted to do `update=":userForm"` (since you can't update the panel directly as [siebz0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704616/siebz0r) pointed out):

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{user.updateDeadlineDate}" update=":userForm"/>

<p:panel id= "myPanel" rendered="#{user.deadline != null}">
     .. some component that needs user.deadline

</p:panel>
```

The `getDeadline` is unnecessary, when you reference backing bean properties just use their names like `deadline`.

Note that you can use the validator of the calendar component, so you can avoid the additional `<f:validator validatorId = "dateValidator"/>` tag.

Your `<f:attribute name="minDate" value="#{user.minDate}" />` tag is probably unnecessary in this case. If you want to set your `deadline` to the value of `minDate` (since they are in the same bean) just do:

```
public void updateDeadlineDate(DateSelectEvent event) {
    mindDate = event.getDate()
    this.setDeadline(mindDate);
}
```

and remove the `<f:attribute name="minDate" value="#{user.minDate}" />`.

Finally I would use the `empty` keyword in the `rendered` attribute instead of `!= null`: `rendered="#{not empty user.deadline}"`

Comment: The OP's update target is correct. You cannot update an element that is not rendered because the client doesn't know of the existence of the element.

Comment: you are right @siebz0r, I overlooked that case. My answer is corrected.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing those out, its working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

- Instead of using `#{user.getDeadline}` you can use `#{user.deadline}`.
- The `f:attribute name="minDate"` is a duplicate of `p:calendar mindate="#{userr.minDate}"` remove either one.
- There is a default validator for `p:calendar`, unless you're doing special validation remove the `<f:validator>`.
- The bean must be at least view scoped (not request scoped) for this to work.

A very common cause for this problem is that the update target is set wrong. Please check in your browser using firebug or some kind of element inspection what id is set for the parent of the panel.

Something to keep in mind when using the `rendered` attribute is that the element is not visible to the client. You have to instruct the client to update the parent of the not-rendered element. (It seems you're already doing this.)

If the calendar and the panel are in the same form you can use `@form` as the target. Doing so the form of the element will be updated. (This is probably what you want.)

```
<p:calendar id="dt"
        value="#{user.deadline}"
        pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"                        
        showOn="button"
        mindate="#{userr.minDate}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{user.updateDeadlineDate}" update="@form"/>
</p:calendar>

<p:panel id= "myPanel" rendered="#{user.getDeadline != null}">
    .. some component that needs user.deadline
</p:panel>
```

Bonus: [click here for more handy update targets](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf).